# How to Stop appearing command prompt at startup?

Tags: windows, cmd

I m facing this problem since last week but couldn't find any workable solution for me. windows command prompt appear in start up then i must enter explorer.exe then window open for me. it don't directly open.

[image]

I hide all Microsoft program from msconfig. some suggest me to update window in latest version i did that too. some told me to run various kind of command like scf/scanner. i did that also.. but this is not worked for me.. can anyone one help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that your question is remotely on topic here, but here's my suggestion.

At the prompt, type the following and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

```cmd
%__AppDir__%reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /V Shell /D "explorer.exe" /F
```

Then type the following and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

```cmd
%__AppDir__%shutdown.exe /R /T 1
```

Your PC will reboot, and hopefully return to its normal explorer interface.

Comment: After obviously trying multiple other sites, and following generic, guesses on what to do by inexperienced or unknowledgeable responders, I would have appreciated some feedback on my answer MhDip. Simply marking my offered solution as accepted, does not help future readers to understand what happened or whether it worked exactly as intended. It is both polite, and costs nothing, to support members and the site by informing them that their efforts to help you with your specific issue were not wasted.